# How to add closing button script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Multi Level Push menu and trying to add a button to make it close.

Basic HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Push Wrapper -->
        <div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">
        <!-- mp-menu -->
            <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
                <div class="mp-level">
                <a class="icon icon-star" href="#" onclick="closeMe();" id="linkk">Exit</a>
    </div>
            </nav>
                <div class="scroller"><!-- this is for emulating position fixed of the nav -->
                <div class="scroller-inner">
                    <!-- Top Navigation -->
<div><a href="#" id="trigger" class="">Button</a></div>
</div><!-- /scroller-inner -->
            </div><!-- /scroller -->
        </div><!-- /pusher -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

JS:

```
new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ), document.getElementById( 'trigger' ) );

 function closeMe(){
 var container = document.getElementById( 'mp-pusher'; );
 classie.remove( container, 'mp-pushed'; );
 scrollToAnchor('#link');
 };
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xs1j8kq5/3/

I am using external resources, of course. The above code for the exit button does not function properly.

How can I close the sidebar menu, and if possible, scroll to an anchor point somewhere on the site?

Comment: First fix your code: `document.getElementById( 'mp-pusher'; );` remove the `;` in the functoin. Should be like this: `document.getElementById( 'mp-pusher');` Do it in the `classie.remove` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fix your code as i mentioned in my comment. There are several syntax errors. And define closeMe before your you call it. Now scrollToAnchor not works, define that before closeMe also.

Now, when you clicked the `Exit` it's not animated, but i think, now you can figure out what to do with it to animate. http://jsfiddle.net/xs1j8kq5/22/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeMe() {
        var container = document.getElementById('mp-pusher');
        classie.remove(container, 'mp-pushed');
        classie.remove(container, 'mp-pusher');
        container.style.transform = "translate3d(+300px, 0px, 0px)";
        //scrollToAnchor('#services');
    }
    ;
</script>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Push Wrapper -->
    <div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">
        <!-- mp-menu -->
        <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
            <div class="mp-level">
                <a class="icon icon-star" href="#" onclick="closeMe();" id="linkk">Exit</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="scroller"><!-- this is for emulating position fixed of the nav -->
            <div class="scroller-inner">
                <!-- Top Navigation -->
                <div><a href="#" id="trigger" class="">Button</a></div>
            </div><!-- /scroller-inner -->
        </div><!-- /scroller -->
    </div><!-- /pusher -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

For scroll, you need to define an `<a name="services"></a>` tag where you want to scroll.

edit: working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xs1j8kq5/24/

Comment: hm, it's true. i'll check.

Comment: @lolka_bolka -It does close the bar, but it opens a blank 300px sidebar on the left - it is hard to notice in the fiddle as they are both blue

Comment: I suggest you to use the version 2 of this plugin, so you can use callbacks, and that seems to me to use much more simple

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `jQuery` in your tags, here is a shorter jQuery equivalent of your code (which does not require an attribute-based event handler):

```
new mlPushMenu($('#mp-menu')[0], $('#trigger')[0]);
$(function () {
    $('#linkk').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   // Stop any scrolling to the bookmark link
        classie.remove($('#mp-pusher'));
        classie.remove($('#mp-pushed'));
        scrollToAnchor('#services');
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xs1j8kq5/23/

Comment: @lolka_bolka: What browser are you using? I get no error, but what are the steps to get the error?

Comment: Friefox: `TypeError: elem.classList is undefined: elem.classList.remove( c );`

Comment: @lolka_bolka: You may have noticed that error refers to code inside the plugin :) I have updated the `classie` code to parallel yours.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your 'trigger' when you instantiate 'mlPushMenu'
So, just state:

```
new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ),
document.getElementById( 'trigger' ) )
```

replacing the id of your button.
In this particular case use '**linkk**':

```
new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ),
document.getElementById( 'linkk' ) )
```

You could use a **class**, and affect as many '**a**'s as you want:

```
new mlPushMenu(document.getElementById('mp-menu'),
document.getElementsByClassName('menu-trigger'));
```

Comment: with getElementsByClassName gives you a javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: Yes @azuax. Then, if you are using a collection of objects, instead of a single (ID) one, you need to change the trigger listner. Use a forEach cycle and test for addEventListener  inside.

Comment: thanks, I try that but didn't work either. Finally I pass an array of Ids (because I need two trigger buttons) and change the mpPushMenu coding.

Comment: I'll try to pass here the blocks I used on a project of mine. There's de 'mp-menu' at the left and 'img work area' at the right.  
The intantiation:  
   var RightPage = new mlPushMenu(document.getElementById('mp-rightPage'), [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a.button--gallery')));

Comment: And the listners, to the right 'img work area':  
    this.triggerPage.forEach(function(button__gallery) {
                          button__gallery.addEventListener( rightPage.eventtype, function( ev ) {     //      ==> clicked on the still opened main page, to go to the rightPage!
                                rightPage._openPageRight(rightPage, button__gallery.href);
                            });
                    });  
Hope it helps!